# How to change SpriteKit's coordinate system

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

All `SKSpriteNode`s have their origin, also called `anchorPoint`, if I'm not wrong, in their middle. I want to translate that origin to be in the middle of the top line of the node. I've tried the following inside the `init()` method, but it doesn't work:

```
self.anchorPoint = self.anchorPoint.applying(
    CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: 0, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
)
```

**PS:** I'm using this to simplify the following:
I've created an array of SpriteNodes, which all have are in the new `CGPoint.zero` position, then, i'll have to apply this on them:

```
for i in 0..<arr.count {
    arr[i].position.y += self.size.height*CGFloat((i+1)/(arr.count+1))
}
```

---

### Here is the code:

```
import SpriteKit

class SKLayer: SKSpriteNode {

init(inside scene: SKScene, withLabels texts: [String]) {
    super.init(texture: nil, color: .clear, size: scene.size)

    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    converted(texts).forEach(self.addChild(_:))

    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    self.position = .zero
}

private func converted(_ text: [String]) -> [SKNode] {

    var arr = [SKLabelNode]()

    text.forEach {
        arr.append(SKLabelNode(text: $0))
    }

    for i in 0..<arr.count {
        arr[i].position.y = CGFloat(i) * arr[0].frame.height
    }

    return arr
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError()
}

}
```

---

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.addChild(
        SKLayer(inside: self, withLabels: ["Welcome", "Hello", "Bye", "Help"])
    )
}

}
```

---

Here's the pic of what the code compiles to:
[image: ScreenShot]

I want the nodes to go from up to down, not the other way around. Iow, I wanna see the "Welcome" Label at the top, then the "texT" one, then the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode),

This is how anchor points work:

> Anchor points are specified in the unit coordinate system, shown in the following illustration. The unit coordinate system places the origin at the bottom left corner of the frame and (1,1) at the top right corner of the frame. A sprite’s anchor point defaults to (0.5,0.5), which corresponds to the center of the frame.

[image]

From this image, we can see that to set the anchor point to the middle of the top border, you need to set it to `(0.5, 1)`.

You tried to transform the anchor point to `self.frame.size / 2` which is probably a number larger than 1. Well, according to the docs, the range of `(0, 0) - (1, 1)` covers the whole frame of the sprite node. If you set it to a value larger than (1, 1), the anchor point will be outside of the frame of the node.

Comment: okay, that works great, but the problem remains on the inside of the node. I want to change the coordinates system on the inside of the node also. What I mean, is that I want the children of this particular node to be placed in respect for the new anchor point

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want to do exactly. Can you show an example of what you want to do by editing the question? My guess based on the current information is that you need to call the `convert(_:from:)` methods. Look that up. @Fayyouz

Comment: @Fayyouz After you set the anchor point, that anchor point will be (0, 0) in the node's coordinate space. Isn't that already "in respect for the new anchor point"?

Comment: I think I can give you an example. Let's name the node we're working in an `SKLayer`. After I set the anchor point, it became (0, 0) only for its parent node. But when I place a new `SKLabelNode` inside the `SKLayer`, at position `.zero`, the new `SKLabelNode` appears in the middle of the `SKLayer`, not at the top.

Comment: @Fayyouz Can you provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example (basically some code that I can copy and paste into Xcode and reproduce the problem)? Because that shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Fayyouz, I think you are confusing yourself,  anchorPoint does not define the coordinate system,  the anchor point of the parent node will not affect the children nodes.  You should be treating your anchor point like a thumbtack,  having your children move in relation to it just seems wrong.  If I thumbtack a paper with sticky notes on it to a bulletin board,  I wouldn't expect the sticky notes to move when I change the location of the thumbtack.

Comment: @Sweeper I'll try to in a minute

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I want them to do that.

Comment: @Sweeper I updated the question with the code. Please check it

Comment: @Fayyouz I think I see what you need to do now. Coordinate systems in sprite kit are different from those in UIKit. In SpriteKit, the higher you go, the larger the `y`. So `arr[i].position.y = CGFloat(i) * sampleLabel.frame.height` should probably be changed to `arr[i].position.y = CGFloat(arr.count - 1- i) * sampleLabel.frame.height`. Also, the code you provided isn't quite an MCVE. What is `SKButton`? Therefore I can't test it.

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry, forgot the SKButton, just treat it as a normal rectangular SKSpriteNode. A couple of minutes and i'll give u an MCVE.

Comment: @Fayyouz Sorry if it was unclear.  ([mcve]). Anyway, did the fix work for you?

Comment: @Sweeper I updated the code. And thanks alot, the fix worked

Comment: @Fayyouz If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it!